# Sent email from IOS Simulator but not receiving in mailbox

Tags: ios, email, simulator, messageui

Here is my code:

```
- (void)sendMail:(id)sender{
    // Email Subject
    NSString *emailTitle = @"Test Email";
    // Email Content
    NSString *messageBody = @"Learning iOS Programming"; // Change the message body to HTML
    // To address
    NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"khi_nakhan@yahoo.com"];

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
    [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:YES];
    [mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

    // Present mail view controller on screen
    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
     }

- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Close the Mail Interface
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Ugh, you should format that code, it's pretty much unreadable like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't send mail from `Simulator`. You need to setup `Mail Account` from `Settings` to be able to do that, which is not available in `Simulators Settings`, its available only in `Devices`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send email from simulator as the mail setup option is not available there. Use an actual iPhone / iPad that has mail configured and then test your app.